# Data structure for ngrams

Tags: javascript, data-structures, n-gram

I have built an ngram model implementation in Javascript, which works fine. However, I am looking to change my data structure so that I do not have to iterate through all the history each time a new word/character is observed.

Here, I take a seedtext and use it to build ngrams with an order 2.

```js
  var ngrams = {};
  var order = 2;
  var seedtext = "adadwsdawdsadawdsadadasdwdadaaasdsadsdadwdasdasd";
  
 build();
  
  function build(){
   
      for (var i = 0; i < seedtext.length - order; i++) {
        var gram = seedtext.substring(i, i + order);
        var next = seedtext.charAt(i + order);

        if (!ngrams.hasOwnProperty(gram)) {
          ngrams[gram] = [];
        }
        
        ngrams[gram].push(next);
      }
  }
  
  console.log(ngrams);
  console.log(ngrams["wd"]);
```

I am looking to have a data structure that holds a record of each observed pattern (for a given order. Each observed pattern should have a *next possible observation* and its count.

For example, if you run the below code, an output such as this can be seen:

```
[object Object] {
  aa: ["a", "s"],
  ad: ["a", "w", "a", "a", "a", "a", "s", "w"],
  as: ["d", "d", "d", "d"],
  aw: ["d", "d"],
  da: ["d", "w", "w", "d", "s", "d", "a", "d", "s", "s"],
  ds: ["a", "a", "a", "d"],
  dw: ["s", "d", "d"],
  sa: ["d", "d", "d"],
  sd: ["a", "w", "s", "a", "a"],
  wd: ["s", "s", "a", "a"],
  ws: ["d"]
}

["s", "s", "a", "a"]
```

Now, if we take "ad" for example: `ngrams["ad"]`, we get back `["a", "w", "a", "a", "a", "a", "s", "w"]`.

Clearly, after `ad` we can either get a `w`,`a` or `s`.

I'd like to group the letters so that `ngrams["ad"]` returns something like:

```
{a: 5
w: 2
s :1}
```

Note that they are in order so that the most frequently occurring letter is at the top, with its count.

I'd like to be able to access the data like so (for example):

```
ngrams["ad"].a;
ngrams["ad"].w;
ngrams["ad"].s;
```

and get back `5` for `a`, 2 for `w` and 1 for `s`.

I also want to be able to increment the values as a previously seen pattern is observed again... I also want to be able to remove patterns.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version. Instead of an array, you add another object to store counts of next characters in it.

```js
        var ngrams = {};
  var order = 2;
  var seedtext = "adadwsdawdsadawdsadadasdwdadaaasdsadsdadwdasdasd";
  
 build();
  
  function build(){
   
      for (var i = 0; i < seedtext.length - order; i++) {
        var gram = seedtext.substring(i, i + order);
        var next = seedtext.charAt(i + order);

        if (!ngrams.hasOwnProperty(gram)) {
          ngrams[gram] = {};
        }
        
        if (!ngrams[gram].hasOwnProperty(next)) {
          ngrams[gram][next] = 0;
        }

        ngrams[gram][next] += 1;
      }
  }
  
  console.log(ngrams);
  console.log(ngrams["wd"]);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!